# Error when using Vagrant to provision with Ansible using pause action

Tags: vagrant, ansible

I am using the Vagrant provision command with Ansible. When it gets to a pause action in the playbook it causes an error.

This is what's in the playbook:

```
- name: Wait for user to copy SSH public key
  action: pause prompt="Plase add the SSH public key above to your GitHub account"
```

This is the error:

```
fatal: [default] => Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible/runner/__init__.py", line 382, in _executor
    exec_rc = self._executor_internal(host, new_stdin)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible/runner/__init__.py", line 471, in _executor_internal
    return self._executor_internal_inner(host, self.module_name, self.module_args, inject, port, complex_args=complex_args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible/runner/__init__.py", line 654, in _executor_internal_inner
    result = handler.run(conn, tmp, module_name, module_args, inject, complex_args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible/runner/action_plugins/pause.py", line 103, in run
    tcflush(sys.stdin, TCIFLUSH)
error: (25, 'Inappropriate ioctl for device')


FATAL: all hosts have already failed -- aborting
```

Answer (score 1):

This is due to the way Vagrant runs Ansible playbooks. The playbook is run in it's entirety and then the output is presented to the user after. You can confirm this happens by replacing your blocking pause with:

```
action: pause seconds=10
```

Ansible will run the playbook showing "[default] Running provisioner: ansible..." and nothing else until 10 seconds is over (and the rest of the playbook has finished).

Comment: Is there a workaround to use ansible's pause module, or an alternative method, within Vagrant?